# Question on number theory

Tags: number-theory

If a²+(5/2)b²+c²= 2ab+bc+ca then a+2b+2c equals what? I am unable to think how to solve it.. Please help

Comment: One trivial solution is $a=b=c=0$  The question is if there are others.  Why or why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:$(a-2b)^2+(b-c)^2+(c-a)^2=0$

Comment: How did u get this?

Comment: @danny, by completing the squares